# Upgrade HDP via Ambari

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I'm upgrading my cluster from HDP2.4 to HDP2.5

Following [the instructions](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.5.0.3/bk_ambari-upgrade/bk_ambari-upgrade.pdf), I already performed the ambari-server and ambari-agent upgrades. I wanna now upgrade HDP thanks to "Manager Versions > Register version" action in Ambari admin interface.

The problem is that i'm not able to "Save" (the button "Save" is **disabled** - see orange circle in image below) even once I've provided the tight Base URL for my OS (redhat 7). I don't know why ...

[image: Ambari admin screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found after inspecting the AngularJS code of the button : I had to give a version number in the top right text input.